# Try to apply function on pandas DataFrame to calculate score?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, user-defined-functions

i created the user define function as given below and tried apply to DataFrame,but got error:- "TypeError: ("scoreq() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ADVTG_TRGT_INC', 'AGECD', and 'PPXPRI'", 'occurred at index ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT')"

```
def scoreq(PCT_NO_OPEN_TRDLN, ADVTG_TRGT_INC, AGECD, PPXPRI):
        scoreq += -0.3657
        scoreq += (ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT in ('2'))*-0.039
        scoreq += (ADVTG_TRGT_INC in ('7','6','5','4'))*0.1311
        scoreq += (AGECD in ('7','2'))*-0.1254
        scoreq += (PPXPRI in (-1))*-0.1786
        return scoreq
        
df_3Var['scoreq'] = df_3Var.apply(scoreq)

"TypeError: ("scoreq() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ADVTG_TRGT_INC', 'AGECD', and 'PPXPRI'", 'occurred at index ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT')"
 


df_3Var:- 
    ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT   ADVTG_TRGT_INC    AGECD   PPXPRI
0                     1                5        6       -1
1                     2                6        5       -1
2                     1                2        2       -1
3                     2                7        6      133
4                     2                1        3       75
```

Comment: Youre not using any args. Do `.apply(scoreq, PCT_NO_OPEN_TRDLN, ADVTG_TRGT_INC, AGECD, PPXPRI)`, also initiallize scoreq. Though you don't really need apply for this

Answer (score 0):

The function called by 'apply' should accept a row or a column. Here's an implementation that works.

Note that you should also:

- Initialize `scoreq`.
- Treat the values as numbers rather than strings.
- Use 'in' against lists and not tuples.

```
    def scoreq(row):
        scoreq = 0 # you need to initialize this variable. 
        scoreq += -0.3657
        scoreq += (row["ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT"] == 2)*-0.039
        scoreq += (row["ADVTG_TRGT_INC"] in [7,6,5,4])*0.1311
        scoreq += (row["AGECD"] in [7,2])*-0.1254
        scoreq += (row["PPXPRI"] == -1)*-0.1786
        return scoreq
            
    df_3Var['scoreq'] = df_3Var.apply(scoreq, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank for your prompt response. but i have string variables in my dataFrame like gender(contains value M, F and U etc), new_VPBUDCAT(contains value A, B etc). like in def function "ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT" is string variable 2 for not married , 1 for married. in that case i have to use quote. ADVNTG_MARITAL_STAT, ADVTG_TRGT_INC, AGECD string variables and PPXPRI is in int..

Answer (score 0):

You used columns name as an arguments in `scoreq` function, but that is not how it works. It should receives regular arguments.

You have two options: send entire row to `scoreq`, or send only relevant values:

```py
def scoreq(row):
        scoreq = row["...."]
        ...
        return scoreq

df_3Var['scoreq'] = df_3Var.apply(scoreq)
```

or send directly only values:

```py
df_3Var['scoreq'] = df_3Var.apply(lambda row: scoreq(row["..."], row["..."]))
```

Also, you may want to handle numbers inside `scoreq` function as numbers and not as string: e.g. `scoreq += (row["PPXPRI"]==(-1))*-0.1786` and not `in`.